# Kernel compile errors

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
kernel/sched. c896e22 warning unused variable 'cpuacct_subsys' [-Wunused-variable] 
    struct cgroup_subsys cpuacct_subsys= { 

    kernel/sched. c743726 warning unused variable 'sysctl_timer_migration' [-Wunused-variable] 
    const_debug unsigned int sysctl_timer_migration=1 

    In file included from kernel/sched_debug. c: 17 e, 

    fron kernel/sched. c1921 
    include/linux/utsnane. H8928 warning unused variable 'uts_sen' [-Wunused-variable] 
    extern struct rw_senaphore uts_sem 

    kernel/sched. At top level 

    kernellsched. c141513 warning 'cpuacct_charge' used but never defined 
    static void cpuacct_charge(struct task_struct· tsk, u64 cputine) 

    kernel/sched. c141613 warning 'cpuacct_update_stats' used but never defined 
    static void cpuacct_update_stats(struct task_struct· tsk, 

    kernel/sched. c152412 warning 'task_hot' used but never defined
```

static int task_hot(struct task_struct"p. u64 now, struct sched_domain· sd)

```
kernel/sched. c181713 warning 'cale_load_account_idle' used but never defined 
static void: a 1 c_load_account_idle(struct rq· this_rq) 
kernel/sched. c1818:13 warning 'update_sysctl' used but never defined 
static void update_sysctl(void) 

kernellsched. c181912 warning 'get_update_sysctl_factor' used but never defined 
static int e t_update_sysctl_factor(void) 

in file included fron kernel/sched. c191B e 

kernel/sched_stride. c16629 warning 'pick_next_task_stride' defined but not used [-Wunused-function] 

static struct task_struct· "k_next_task_stride(struct rq 'rq) 
scripts/nakefile. Build230 recipe for target ' kernel/sched. o' failed 
nake[1] '' [kernellsched. o] Error 1 

Hakefile884 recipe for target kernel' failed 

make*** [kernel] Error 2
```

---

I am stuck at this. I am trying to Compile kernel version 2.6.35.5 by adding stride scheduler.  After removing basic errors.... whole sched.c is giving errors now.

Comment: Please, edit yout question to format error message as a code. Just select it and press Ctrl+k. Otherwise it is unreadable.

Comment: These are just warnings about unused variables/functions, they do not prevent compiling. If you have compiler option `-Werror` set, unset it.

Comment: I don't see any problematic in the excerpts you showed. Try to find the word `error` in the output and copy'n'paste few lines around it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sir , I am new to linux system programming. I don't know how to unset it. Will you please guide me.

Comment: In addition,  I have only posted a little part of these problems.  There are so many errors occurring in compilation.  All from sched.c .... before removing errors from sched_stride.c these errors were not occurring at that time. When I fix the stride problems.... this happened.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko  Sir,  I'll post those error ASAP.

Comment: @ZawarShahid, linux kernel code is written on C. If you know C language, you should face with compilation output before. If you new in C language, kernel is not suitable area for learn it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sir, I am not that new .... I know all about C language. Even I have embedded a system call in linux kernel 3.16 before.

Comment: @ZawarShahid, your compiler output looks broken... Can you just copy your actual build log to your question? Also it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your actual code. So if you can, please upload your kernel repo to GitHub or something like that (and add your code as separate commit). Then add link to your repo to the question. Without the code we are unable to debug your code and tell what gone wrong.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Sir, I have made stride scheduling policy. There is no error in that.... but I, ll post the whole log so that you can understand it in a better way. Also, errors are coming from kernel/sched.c not from my sched_stride.c file.

Comment: @SamProtsenko https://www.dropbox.com/s/htl1nb2bmq4mlii/Errornull.txt?dl=0

Comment: @ZawarShahid, Please provide **complete** build log. And we also need your sources (exactly code of yours kernel that you try to build, as it described in my previous comment). Without this information it's extremely hard to figure out what is causing that error.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Sir I have provided the complete log of error in my previous comment. And now posting the link to the source files .

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/in4pkro7tcv515u/sched.c?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/027xo5evtrsysqr/sched.h?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2rs7ednercc76j/sched_stride.c?dl=0

Comment: @SamProtsenko  I have provided the links to the source files above.

Comment: @ZawarShahid Ok, which architecture you are compiling it for? And what is the version of your GCC?

Comment: @SamProtsenko I am compiling kernel version 2.6.35.5 and my current linux kernel version is 3.16 is guess... not sure.

Comment: @ZawarShahid I was asking about **architecture** that you are building it for. E.g. `x86`, `arm`, etc. And also what is your compiler version (GCC)?

Comment: @SamProtsenko My GCC version is 4.9.1 and the architecture is x86_64